# How can I produce AC with a DC offset, isolated from my AC supply

Tags: dc-offset

I'm working on a project to provide remote control for model trains. The trains I am using are AC powered with approximately 0-20VAC applied to the rails. They have two features: directional control and sound effects. Traditionally, all signaling is performed over the rails from the power supply:

- Speed is controlled by varying the voltage
- Sound effects are toggled by applying a +/-2.5V DC offset to the AC wave

This has some disadvantages which I want to fix:

- Poor low-speed running since low-speed = low input power
- Can't independently control multiple trains on the same track circuit

To do this, I'm designing a custom PCB which replaces part of the internal electronics of the train. The trains I am modifying generally have two main electrical components, though the form they take has varied over the years.

1. The directional controller. This toggles the direction through four states, forward -> neutral (reverse next) -> reverse -> neutral (forward next), each time the power supply AC voltage is turned off (so you change direction by turning it off and on again).
2. The sound controller. This plays sound effects when triggered by a DC offset voltage applied to its AC power supply.

   - Older models use a relay that activates a motor to drive a mechanical whistle
   - Newer models use a variety of different PCB designs which mimic the signal detection of the old analog systems. Unlike old systems, some of these can tell whether the DC offset is positive or negative and use that to decide between two different sets of sound effects.
   - For both models, there are exactly 3 possible signal states that the sound controller cares about:

     - `OFF`: Signaled by a plain AC wave from the power supply
     - `HORN`: Signaled by a positive DC offset applied to the AC power
     - `BELL`: Signaled by a negative DC offset applied to the AC power

In existing trains, both of these components are separately wired into the 0-20VAC track power and are just looking for different signals.

The direction controller isn't important here, because I'm removing it entirely and replacing it with a modern motor controller. That also leads to the first part of the control scheme changing: in my system, track voltage is always set to ~maximum, around 18-20VAC, and the speed and direction are controlled wirelessly.

However, I don't want to fully replace the sound controller. I want to keep the existing sound effects which came with the train but be able to control them wirelessly from the same PCB that I'm using to control the motors.

Since the existing sound controller expects a DC-offset signal applied to the ~18VAC supply voltage, I need to be able to create a DC-offset-AC signal on demand when when the wireless controller ask for it.

In [Version 1](https://youtu.be/EYEvNaZX4bU), I used my microcontroller and a motor controller to drive an AC square wave with a variable midpoint to control this sound board. I found that that approach works for some of the sound boards but not others, so I have one train with a fully functional horn and one where it outputs lots of weird static and triggers randomly.

I believe that to make the system work reliably for all sound controllers across all trains I may want to modify, I can't use an AC square wave for the sound controller. I need to supply (relatively) smooth AC for normal power to the sound controller and then cause an offset somehow when I need to tell the sound controller to play sounds.

My circuit board has 3 power sources to work with. First is the ~18VAC input voltage. Second is the ~18VDC rectified and smoothed input voltage, which is used to drive the motors. Last is a 3.3VDC rail used for the microcontroller and the the radio.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS9d33.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can I apply a toggleable DC offset to an AC wave in this system? Open to options that act on both the original input signal (as long as the DC is isolated from the track) and options that generate a new wave from the rectified DC. Cutting off part of the AC waveform on one side should also work, as I believe all modern power supplies for these trains use a [chopped wave](https://ogrforum.ogaugerr.com/topic/152899749132015893?reply=152899749156619128#152899749156619128) to vary the effective voltage and just cut the wave at a different point in each direction to trigger sound effects.

My background is CS not CE or EE, so I'm not sure what to look for or what kinds of components might be available for something like this.

Comment: Why does the audio require something such a strange control scheme? Is that "negative offset" actually negative (below 0V) or did you mean simply below 2.5V.

Comment: The control scheme is backwards compatible with systems from the 1950s which used the DC offset to trip a relay to activate a motor that blew a physical whistle. In the old systems, a DC offset in either direction would work, but more modern systems expanded the control scheme by having a DC offset in one direction mean "horn" and the other direction mean "bell". So when I say negative offset, I mean I need to apply offsets in opposite directions relative to the two AC leads.

Comment: What happens when your AC source voltage drops below 3.3V????

Comment: @KyleB Things go into brownout or shut down I guess. IDK, it's a normal thing to happen when turning the power on or off and I've never had a problem with that.

Comment: Sure - I mean like if somebody is running the train really slow, that AC voltage will be very low right?  Then your fancy digital stuff won't work at that time.   Seems like something that would really irk your customers.  Maybe they all do that???   A fancier voltage regulator would allow you to either cut or BOOST the input voltage as necessary (google "boost/buck regulator").  What you have currently can only cut.

Comment: If it actually works the way you want, it will be very noisy because of poor contacts (tracks) and the motors on the same power supply. You have to go digital or send audio wireless for example with a bluetooth amp module and a isolated DC/DC converter inside the train.

Comment: @KyleB The point of the project is to remote control the trains, so the track power is always set to near maximum when using this system; it eliminates using the track voltage to control the speed. That's why I need to be able to manually trigger the sound controller from a microcontroller; if I was using track voltage to control the speed, I would use track voltage to control the sound effects too. All the power supplies I use can already generate the necessary DC offset to trigger sound effects, I want to be able to do it independently in each train when commanded to wirelessly.

Comment: @Codebeat The sound controller is a preexisting, self-contained PCB which is already designed to operate in this environment. It has all the necessary audio data stored internally. All my DC offset signal is doing is telling it *when* I want it to play the audio that it has stored.

Comment: @zstewart Remember we know nothing, the MCU you use, the protocol you want to use, how the modules look like, configuration etc. Sure you can send a signal thru an AC-line (like powerline ethernet) but that isn't easy to do. It isn't the signal alone, you have to deal with noise, failure checks, you need a protocol etc. It isn't just sending a signal because noise can be also a signal and that is a signal you don't want. This is very complicated. You made a design, what kind design did you made that u don't want to change? Take a look at the protocol of Honeywell boilers however that is DC.

Comment: @zstewart If you make your trains wireless controlled, you can easily do what you want. Provide via the tracks the power required and control the train wireless. For example, take a look at the ESP32, it has everything you need and can be very small. Maybe you have to accept that some designs is not the best way to do it. I think you made it very complicated for somebody that hasn't the background to do it complicated.

Comment: @Codebeat I already have a fully-functional wireless control system, thank you. I am now trying to use the microcontroller I have to operate an existing sound board that came with the train. That existing sound board expects a DC offset signal applied to its AC power supply to tell it "play sounds now", so my control scheme for that sound board is exactly as complicated as necessary. I'm not sending sound data over an AC line, the signal is not nearly as complicated as you seem to think! There are exactly three states: ON+ (AC + DC), OFF (AC only), ON- (AC - DC)

Answer (score 2):

Use a DC block capacitor with resistive biasing. As long as not too much power is required this should work (it's normally only used to bias signals).

If more power is required then your MCU/H-bridge inverter approach is simplest but you just need to add lots of filtering.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4Cxkz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Does this still work even though the DC supply is rectified from the AC supply? That is, the DC ground is always tied to whichever side of the AC supply is lowest through the bridge rectifier, so I'm not sure how that affects this setup.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: What is the complete circuit here? How That is, where do I connect the rest of the AC circuit?

Comment: That's it. The audio label was wrong so I corrected it.

Comment: This works if the input impedance of his digital device is high enough.  (currently undefined).  It likely wouldn't work with the old fashioned relays and such I suspect.

Comment: @KyleB Does the modern version actually use relays though?

Comment: I have no idea how they work today, was just mentioning the possibility for the OP's sake.  they could be straight into a near infinite impedance I/O pin, or there may be some resistor-ladder that an ADC reads.   You alluded to it in your answer but in a way that maybe only an EE would understand your meaning.  I was just trying to be clearer for the OP.    If OP is unsure what we mean by "input impedance", he/she should clearly  describe and share the actual hardware being used.

Comment: @KyleB I understand.

Comment: Sorry brother, surely didn't mean to make you think I was being snide with you   ;)   Your rep is 10x mine, I wouldn't dare   LOL

Comment: @KyleB I did not.

Comment: I haven't analyzed the sound control PCB in detail, so I don't know its impedance and I have been treating it as a black box -- also there are at least two, probably more, distinct versions that apparently have different characteristics (one version worked with an AC square wave and the other did not). The one I did look at (the one that already works fine with a square wave input) appeared to be charging two capacitors through diodes pointed in opposite directions and presumably comparing the stored voltages somehow. IIRC the other one didn't have enough capacitors on it to be doing that.