# Is there a better way to digitally phase-control this triac?

Tags: triac, phase-shift, dc-offset

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/646322/116618) which has a more detailed background of the problem I'm trying to solve.

I've built a wireless remote controller for a model train I have that runs on ~18VAC provided through the rails. For this project, I've replaced most of the electronics that came with the train, however one component that I don't want to replace is the original sound-effects circuit board.

For reasons that have to do with backwards-compatibility with [1940s tech](https://postwarlionel.com/everything-else/odds-ends/167-whistle-controller/), the way the sound-effects system works is that it accepts AC power and looks for either a positive or negative DC offset applied to its AC power supply. A positive DC voltage of ~2.5V means "run the horn" and a negative DC voltage means "run the bell". To be clear this is a 3-state system; I don't need to do any kind of precise signaling, just get to one of these three states. [Here's an example](https://i.postimg.cc/TdHLS7fH/Whistle-Control-Theory-Description.jpg) of how this worked in an old analog transformer (I don't currently need the boost voltage described in the example because I'm currently only controlling modern digital systems, not older relay-based systems).

The circuit I've come up with to do this (shown below) is to use a single triac with three parallel control circuits attached to the gate. The first two control circuits are optoisolators which I've copied from [this document from ST](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00451014-controlling-a-triac-with-a-phototriac-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (snubber circuit and all; though I'm not sure whether I need that). The only difference is the two opto-triacs are each gated by diodes in opposite directions, so they independently control the positive and negative half of the AC wave. The third control circuit is a phase-control circuit taken from [this basic tutorial](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/triac.html), though I've had to swap the diac for two zener diodes nose-to-nose because I couldn't find a low-enough voltage diac.

[image: Independent Bidirectional Triac Control]

My intention is that normally, U1 and U2 are on, and the triac is activated equally in both directions. When I want to trigger the horn or bell, I switch off just one of the two opto-triacs. Then the half that's still on continues to receive a full AC wave, while the half that's off switches to being triggered by the phase-control circuit, which delays activation and so causes the AC wave to be uneven -- which creates the DC offset that I need.

My main question is: is there a better way for me to achieve the phase offset portion of this circuit? Or just generally a way to digitally apply phase control? I would prefer to be able to adjust the phase offset programatically, but if I have to I'd be fine with changing the phase-control resistor to a trimmer to allow me to dial it in once I build the circuit.

As a secondary question: how do I deal with current limiting on the triac gate? Do I need to apply e.g. a current limiting resistor to the gate? Especially with this setup where I may have up to two different systems trying to trigger it in parallel (so potentially double the current of any one), or does the triac limit the gate input current itself?

Comment: Are you asking what implementation is recommended to impose a +/- 2.5V DC offset onto an 18V ACrms signal?

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent I'm asking if there's a better way to impose a controlled phase offset on the triac. I think I'm set on using a phase-offset triac with independent control in each AC direction.

Comment: I am not sure about how to this. My first go to would be a little 6pin uC. @zstewart

Comment: How much current is needed for the sound controller when active?